# Customise PHP String Formatting

Tags: php, arrays, string, loops, foreach

I have an HTML Form that contains 20 sets of fields. Here are 2 for an example:

```
<input type="text" class="auto-clear" id="p1weight" name="p1weight" value=""  />     
<input type="text" class="auto-clear" id="p1length" name="p1length" value="" />     
<input type="text" class="auto-clear" id="p1width" name="p1width" value="" />    
<input type="text" class="auto-clear" id="p1height" name="p1height" value="" />    

<input type="text" class="auto-clear" id="p2weight" name="p2weight" value="" />    
<input type="text" class="auto-clear" id="p2length" name="p2length"  value="" />     
<input type="text" class="auto-clear" id="p2width" name="p2width" value="" />    
<input type="text" class="auto-clear" id="p2height" name="p2height" value="" />
```

I am using the following PHP code to generate a string (**$all**) to store the field values:

```
foreach( range( 1, 20) as $i)
    {
        // Create an array that stores all of the values for the current number
        $values = array( 
            'p' . $i . 'weight' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'weight'],
            'p' . $i . 'length' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'length'], 
            'p' . $i . 'width' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'width'], 
            'p' . $i . 'height' => $_POST['p' . $i . 'height'] 
        );

        $all .= implode( '|', $values) . "\n\n";
    }
```

If my input for the 2 sets of fields is 1, 2, 3 & 4, this gives my **$all** value as: `1|2|3|4 1|2|3|4`.

However, I would like to customise this more. Ultimately, I would like my **$all** to be:

```
Item1: Weight (kg):1 Length (cm): 2 Width (cm): 3 Height (cm): 4
Item2: Weight (kg):1 Length (cm): 2 Width (cm): 3 Height (cm): 4
```

How do I update my PHP above to achieve this?

Many thanks for any pointers.

Comment: Textbook "too localized". Voting to close.

Comment: I suggest looking into html templates.  There are ways to probably do this in PHP, but it's going to be more of a headache than it's worth.   In your case, the easiest approach would be a foeach loop and just mapping the value types to the value, using a counter to indicate the item #

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
foreach( range( 1, 20) as $i)
        {

            $all .= "Item".$i.": Weight (kg):".$_POST['p' . $i . 'weight']." Length (cm): ".$_POST['p' . $i . 'length']." Width (cm): ".$_POST['p' . $i . 'width']." Height (cm): ".$_POST['p' . $i . 'height']."\n";
        }
```

Comment: Absolutely perfect, Waseem!!! Many, many thanks. Have a great day!

Comment: please, do not feed [help vampires](http://www.slash7.com/pages/vampires)

Comment: Great answer! No description of what was done, no information on what was modified or improved, or why. If all the answers were like this, we'd learn nothing and love it. `:s`

Comment: Thanks Jared , I will be more descriptive in the next time . :)

Answer (score 1):

You code above is already very fine to normalize the submitted data into the array. To now map the values from the array, you can make use of a function called [`vsprintf`](http://php.net/vsprintf). It takes two arguments. The first one is a formatting string you can add placeholders in that mark the formatting of a value (e.g. `%d` to display as integer number (d = digit)) and the second argument is an array that contains the values:

```
$format = "Item$i: Weight (kg): %d length (cm): %d Width (cm): %d Height (cm): %d \n\n";
$all .= vsprintf($format, $values);
```

The benefit of this method is that you have decoupled value extraction and formatting. You can then move those two parts more away from each other in the future, e.g. multiple types of output.

Additionally this preserves what you have already written which was a great step forward in normalizing the submitted data.